# How to get another interface of a COM instance?

Tags: visual-c++, com

Assume we have a coclass `CLSID_Abc` that provides 2 interfaces `IFoo` and `IBar`. Therefore, we are able to do this already in clients:

```
IFoo *foo = nullptr;
::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Abc, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IFoo, (void **)&foo);
foo->a_method_of_ifoo();
IBar *bar;
foo->QueryInterface(IID_IBar, (void **)&bar);
bar->a_method_of_ibar();
```

Now we want to use the syntax powered by .tlb file. So we can do this

```
using namespace Baz;
IFooPtr foo;
foo.CreateInstance("a_mysterious_string_that_I_dont_know_what_it_is_yet_but_lets_pretend_it_works");
foo->a_method_of_ifoo();
```

The question is how to get the interface `IBar` via `foo` when using the syntax provided by .tlb file?

Comment: [QueryInterface is still there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-ptr-t-queryinterface?view=msvc-160).

Comment: @RaymondChen I just noticed that what QueryInterface receives is obviously not a smart pointer. Is there any way to get a smart pointer like foo in the above code snippet?

Comment: Just read the documentation looking for things that will help. Or read the source code (comip.h). Looks like there is a conversion constructor from any smart pointer to any other. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-ptr-t-com-ptr-t?view=msvc-160